# ¿Capturar id de una lista de etiqueta img con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

El aplicativo lo que trata de hacer es contra una serie de relatos de unos ciudadanos en una serie de video clip, ahora, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es mostrar unas miniaturas.

Estoy tratando de capturar el valor src de una etiqueta img, la cosa es que el id de la img lo tengo en un base de datos, al tratar de pasar ese id por una función para así con jquery tratar de capturar el src no lo hace, me dice que indefinido. alguien me puede decir como puedo hacer para capturar los id de forma dinamica.

```
function marcadoRegionImagen(nombre_video) {
    nombre_video = nombre_video.toLowerCase();
    var src = $(nombre_video).attr('src');
    console.log('funciona? ' + src);
}
```

Esta funcion la llamo al momento de iniciar el reproductor.

```
rep_one.onplay = function () {
            if (parseInt(estado_id_video) >= long.length) {
                getVideo();
            }
            rep = 1;
            $('#video_two').attr('src', video.video[parseInt(estado_id_video) + 1].R);
            estado_id_video = parseInt(estado_id_video) + 1;
            //Aqui le paso el id que vide desde la base de datos
            marcadoRegionImagen(video.video[parseInt(estado_id_video)].V);
        }
```

De esta forma me tendría que permitir mostrar al usuario cual de los diferentes vídeos se encuentra actualmente.

De lado del front-end se tiene una lista de imagenes, mas o menos asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero le estoy pasando el id pero nada, me retorna siempre undefined, Alguien me puede decir como puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el HTML donde está la imagen en cuestión?

Comment: es una lista de imagnes, digamos que los se tiene es algo mas o menos asi <img id="video_01.mp4" src="http://localhost:700/proyecto-daniel/assets/web/img/if_male3_403019.png" alt="">

Comment: Si muestras el HTML y explicas mejor la lógica del programa podrás obtener una respuesta óptima, de lo contrario estarás propiciando respuestas insuficientes como la que ya te ha dado @alanfcm, por lo mismo, porque en un programa hay también un contexto, una lógica según la cual conviene aplicar un código de conveniencia. Si tú no pones el HTML (sólo la parte de la imagen) con el que estás trabajando falta un elemento importante del problema.

Comment: @JhonnyLuis si pasas valores con un punto este debería escaparse. `marcadoRegionImagen("video_01\\.mp4");`  en el parámetro o directamente en la función. Aunque no se recomienda tener identificadores de este tipo :)

Comment: @Dev.Joel de la forma en como esta ingresa video_25.mp4 y sale video_25.mp4, ahora el problema aparecer es que no reconoce $('#' + video_25.mp4).attr('src');

Comment: @JhonnyLuis agregué una pequeña explicación en mi respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si estas pasando el ID, debes concatenarlo con el hashtag `#` asi:

```js
function marcadoRegionImagen(nombre_video) {
    nombre_video = nombre_video.toLowerCase();
    var src = $("#" + nombre_video).attr('src');
    console.log('funciona? ' + src);
}
marcadoRegionImagen("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="hello"></img>
```

Comment: aun asi lo hago pero sigue mostrando undefined

Comment: @JhonnyLuis pon el HTML y muestra cómo llamas a la función y cómo le pasas el parámetro. Puede que el `undefined` se deba a que pasas mal el parámetro o quien sabe a qué...

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes problemas con los caracteres enviados al selector en JQuery, recordar que un punto hace referencia a una clase, por eso sucede esto ya que está enviando el `id` con un punto incluido,

```
$('#video_01.mp4');  // incluirá una clase mp4 a la búsqueda
```

para solucionar puede aplicar una expresión regular para reemplazar el punto  por el `\\` y **escapar** dicho caracter.

```
nombre_video.toLowerCase().replace( /(\.)/g, "\\$1" );
```

```js
function marcadoRegionImagen(nombre_video) {
    nombre_video = nombre_video.toLowerCase().replace( /(\.)/g, "\\$1" );
    var src = $("#" + nombre_video).attr('src');
    console.log('funciona? ' + src);
}
marcadoRegionImagen("video_01.mp4");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="video_01.mp4" src="hello"></img>
```

Aunque puede ser una solución, recomendaría evitar `id` con un el punto incluido.